# How can I convert a multi http request into a component-store effect in ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, rxjs-pipeable-operators, ngrx-component-store

I'm new to ngrx and component-store, and I need to make a variable amount of parallel http requests (based on how many ids I have) to a service, sending a different ID for each one, and in the end, adding all the results into a single one.

Let's say I have something like this (might have some mistakes, I just wrote it down as an example):

```
public apiUrl = 'example.com/prices/books';
public bookIds$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([1, 2, 3, 4]);
public totalAmount = 0;

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit():void {
    this.bookIds$.subscribe(data => {
        this.totalAmount += this.getTotalAmount(data)
    })
}

public getTotalAmount(idArray: number[]): number {
    let subTotal = 0; // to reset the totalAmount before adding book prices
    for (int i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++)
    {
        this.http.get(`${URL}/${idArray[i]}`)
        .subscribe(response => {
            subTotal += response;
        })
    }
    return subTotal
}
```

How can I convert that method into a component-store effect? I need an example to understand what rxjs operators should I use and how, inside an effect like this:

```
this.effect((bookIds$: Observable<number[]>) => { 
    return bookIds$.pipe( 
        // do the forkJoin 
        // do some patchState with the final combined result 
    ) 
}
```

Comment: If you're in control of the backend code, I would look at passing an array of IDs in the request versus making potentially lots of requests. If not, you'll want to look at `forkJoin` in RxJS

Comment: Could you show me a simple example using it, so I can understand how it works? I'm trying my best to implement it in my problem but I can't manage to do so. I'm still learning RxJS and struggling a bit to follow official documentation without simple examples

Answer (score -1):

[forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) takes an array of observables (or an object) and returns an array of values (or an object) in the order the observables were defined when all of the observables emit a value:

```js
forkJoin([
  this.httpClient.get<SomeType>(url1),
  this.httpClient.get<SomeType>(url2),
  this.httpClient.get<SomeType>(url3),
])
.subscribe(responses => {
  const [ value1, value2, value3 ] = responses;
});
```

It's similar in functionality to `Promise.all()`. You can also add error handling on each observable to catch failures. Something to keep in mind is that `forkJoin` won't emit anything if any of the observables error out.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but how would you implement that as an effect of an ngrx component store? (updated the end of my original question to reflect an example of my effect)

Comment: Have your effect call a service method that implements the forkJoin. The values will be returned to you and then you can dispatch another action to handle the "success" of the calls completing